# How can i fail JWT authentication in c# if one of the tokens fails to authenticate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

Currently i have setup two Jwt authentication schemas, and if one of the schemas succeeds in authenticating the user (token), then authentication completes successfully and authorization thinks the user is authenticated. How can i prevent this?

I am using .NET 7 framework.

Comment: Register only one authentication scheme:  A custom scheme that calls the other two.